# Application stopped error in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am a newbie.

I am getting "Application has stopped", error after pressing on Encrypt **button** (id=encb) (only name, for testing by Toast), **in fragment_main.xml (Home)**.

**Explanation:**
**MainActivity.java**, its layout, **activity_main.xml** (Its for already built in navigation bar).
**MainFragment.java**, its layout, **fragment_main.xml** (Its for Home fragment in the navigation bar, from one of the fragments like Home, Settings etc.)

**What I have tried:** I have searched a lot for it on Internet. Checked my onClick ***function***, it ***is correct***.

Also as there is FragmentTransaction of the fragment_main (i.e., 
MainFragment), by activity_main. So, it means **I have to put my onClick() in MainActivity.java instead of MainFragment.java**.

Here is the [code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2x72D21rB9daWc1LWRuWGplWWM).

Every answer will be appreciated.

Comment: Although I have answered your question but **you should add code in your post (question) only not on a 3rd party place**. 99.9% chances are that no one would look into the code if its not in the post.

Comment: Thanks Sir, next time I will put the code here only.

Comment: I don't know what these StackOverflow people want, they should delete the post if they found it not much valuable (for them, I don't know what is their criteria) only after answering, but they should not give a -1. We are newbie, they should remember it :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your buttons are in `fragment_main.xml` which is used in `MainFragment.java` but you are using those buttons in `MainActivity.java`, so it's coming out to be null which results in `NullPointerException`.

**Solution 1:** Use this if you want your buttons in the current fragment only.

Move button related code to `MainFragment.java` like this

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Button b2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.encb);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // click related code goes here
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

**Solution 2:** Use this if you want your button to be there irrespective of the currently loaded fragment.

Add those buttons in `activity_main.xml`